# 301 Redirection not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm having issue while redirecting this. It's not redirecting properly. Does any one know how to write this in effective way.

```
redirect 301 /maldives-accommodation/luxury-boutique-hotels/   /hotels-resorts/luxury-boutique-hotels.html
redirect 301 /maldives-accommodation/luxury-star-class-hotels/   /hotels-resorts/luxury-star-class-hotels.html
redirect 301 /maldives-accommodation/maldives-villas/   /hotels-resorts/villas.html
redirect 301 /maldives-accommodation/   /hotels-resorts.html
```

Comment: What you mean by "not redirecting properly" - does it works or not working at all?

Comment: DOMAIN/maldives-accommodation/luxury-boutique-hotels/ will redirect to DOMAIN/hotels-resorts.html/hotels-resorts/luxury-boutique-hotels.html

Comment: That redirect is simply not possible with the code you have posted, so there must be "something else" going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The `Redirect` directive links two URL path nodes together, so you probably want to use something like `RedirectMatch` instead so everything after the pattern will get ignored:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/maldives-accommodation/luxury-boutique-hotels/$   /hotels-resorts/luxury-boutique-hotels.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/maldives-accommodation/luxury-star-class-hotels/$   /hotels-resorts/luxury-star-class-hotels.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/maldives-accommodation/maldives-villas/$   /hotels-resorts/villas.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/maldives-accommodation/$   /hotels-resorts.html
```